# Cannot get com.android.vending.apk and com.google.android.gms.apk installed

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm a beginner of android developing. I'm working in a project requires google map api.
I followed the success examples posted on Stackoverflow step by step and downloaded com.android.vending-20140218.apk and com.google.android.gms-20140218.apk. Then I copy and paste these two apk files in the same direction of my adb application, under ~/sdk/platform-tools. When I run adb command in my cmd window, first I navigate to my adb path, in my computer it's: A:\Eclipse\eclipse\sdk\platform-tools, then I tried to run the command: adb install com.google.android.gms-20140218.apk, but It failed. cmd shows: no device found. Waiting for device.

I tried many times on different computers. The same problems comes out and didn't get any information by google this problem. Thanks so much for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You should run an android emulator first that you've created. Then check the running device:

```
adb devices
```

if your emulator was detected, you could try to run your:

```
adb install com.google.android.gms-20140218.apk
```